# How to perform sub-queries in Pyspark without joining tables using the API?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, subquery

I'm re-writing some SQL code and there is a section of the code which makes use of sub-queries. I could write this as a join, but wanted to know if it can be done in a similar sub-query manner in Pyspark. There is significant performance benefit by using sub-queries in the SQL code, but want to know if this would be irrelevant in Pyspark due to optimisation in the DAG. So it would be helpful if someone could explain the relative performance tradeoff, if there is a tradeoff.

The logic is pretty simple: I have df_a and I want to pull a column from df_b where df_a and df_b have a matching index on a certain key. The below isn't working but is intended to show the intent.

```
df_a.select("df_a.key_1", "df_a.key_2", df_b.select("df_b.key_2").where(col("df_b.key_1")=="df_a.key_3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your sql code that is working then you can just use `spark.sql(s)` where s is your query as a String. It can contain subqueries too. Just make sure to create a view of your dataframe to use it inside `spark.sql` query. Here is a toy example :

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM people") // put your sql query here containing subqueries
```

As for your question regarding optimisation tradeoff. In theory the catalyst optimizer used by spark should take care of any optimization in your query but as always if you know exactly what kind of optimisation you need then in general it is better do it by hand rather than relying on catalist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Simon, but I made a mistake in my question when I omitted the requirement to use the API instead of Spark SQL. Would you have any advice for how you could do this using the API?